# How to remove logged in user in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm developing an app in Meteor and I want to know how I do can delete a user's account who is logged into the system? I mean that you can delete your account (like Tinder or Facebook) and the application ejects you because you're already deleted, and you no longer exist.

With a simple button of "Delete your account" attached.

[image]

If you could help me; I'm still a novice I'd really appreciate it, I try to retrieve the id of the current user with `Meteor.userId()`, and I was creating a method in the following way:

```
Meteor.methods({
  SuprimirPersona: function(id) {
    var postId = Meteor.userId();
    const userId = this.userId;
    const p = Meteor.users.findOne(postId);
    if (userId && p === userId) {
      Meteor.users.remove({
          postId: this._id
        },
        function(error, result) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("Error removing user:", error);
          } else {
            console.log("users removed:" + result);
          }
        })
    }
  }
});
```

And calling the method in the following way but it does not give any results, I do not understand why:

```
'click #Desactivarr': function() {
  var postId = Meteor.userId();
  Meteor.call('SuprimirPersona', userId, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Somee Error");
    }
  });
  Meteor.logout(function() {
    FlowRouter.go('/');
  });
},
```

Hope someone could help me! Regards!

Comment: you might want to re-format your code

Comment: Looks like it should work if you fixed this line `if (userId && p === userId)`. Since `p` is a user document, not just the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just answered this question on Meteor Forums:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-remove-logged-in-user-in-meteor/42639/3

The issue is you're trying to remove Users by postId, instead of Users.remove({_id: id}). You're removing nothing :)

Comment: Yes, that's why it was not working , Thank you for your explanation!
 the end I it  way and it worked!


   Meteor.call ('DeletePerson', function (error) {
       if (error) {
     console.log ("Somee error", error);
        } 

   Meteor.methods ({
      DeletePerson: function (id) {
          var _id = Meteor.userId ();

            console.log ("id users", id);

            Meteor.users.remove ({_id: this.userId})

    },

})

Comment: @naudi_alvarado, good to know. Typo errors are the worst...
Could you accept my response as "accepted"?

Answer (score 0):

To remove a user from the user's collection. You need to get the userid of the user you want to remove. This you can get by calling Meteor.userId() on the client to get the userid of the user or this.userId on the server. You need to logout the user and after a successful logout you can pass the userid you got to the meteor.users.remove(userId)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some unnecessary things on the client and server side - like getting the same user id multiple times, not even passing it to the server side method and then getting it again.

I think what you are trying to do is get the id of a user that posted something and pass it to the server side, where you check if the poster's id is the same as the id of the current user. If so, you remove the user, otherwise nothing happens.

```
'click #desactivarr' : function() {
  var postID = <get the id of the user you want to delete here>;
  Meteor.call("suprimirPersona", postID, callbackfunc);
}
```

Then on the server side it would be

```
Meteor.methods({
  suprimirPersona : function(postID) {
    var userID = Meteor.userId();
    if (userID && postID === userID) {
      Meteor.users.remove({ postId : userID })
    }
  }
});
```

Meteor.userId() and this.userId return the id of the currently logged in user that is executing the code on the client side or making the request to a server side method.